# using iteration on an objects value in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of dictionaries that looks like this

```
id_dict = {
  "dict_one": {
    "ids": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "start_num": 5
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "end_num": 5
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "start_num": 20
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "end_num": 3
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "start_num": 10
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "end_num": 5
      }
    ]
  },
  "dict_two": {
    "ids": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "start_num": 5
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "end_num": 5
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "start_num": 20
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "end_num": 3
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "start_num": 10
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "end_num": 5
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm trying to create a new dictionary with the different between the two ids start and end nums. It doesn't matter which two ids I match I just need to match two.

so I want to return something like this

```
new_dict = {"num_dif": 2} # for id 1
```

However, there are multiple dictionaries in the array and each set of objects are in different order.

So I would like to be able to write something like this

```
new_dict = {"num_dif": for values in dict if values["id"] match then subtract values["start_num"] - values["end_num"]}
```

if this is possible I just don't know if you can add a for loop as a value on a dictionary.

Comment: Are you sure you are going to have two, and only, two dictionaries with matching id?

Comment: Yes, that was my first concern, but I checked and there will only be two dictionaries with matching ids @DaniMesejo

Comment: @DaniMesejo and the first dict will always been start_num and the second end_num

Comment: What's your expected output? A list of dictionaries?

Comment: `new_dict = {"num_dif": 2} # for id 1 `.So do you just want to get the result for id 1?Or `new_dict = {"num_dif": [2 .....]}`?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA yes I just want to match one set of ids. So it could be any set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a list and then `dict` comprehension:

```
l=[x for x in id_dict if x['id']==1]
new_dict = {'num_dict': l[0]['start_num']-l[1]['end_num']}
```

Comment: So I need to do the iteration on the value because I will be iterating over multiple dictionaries